# Substring first, second, third, ... , n match

Tags: java

Given: `String s = "{aaa}{bbb}ccc`.

How to get an array (or list) which elements will be:

0th element: `aaa`
1st element: `bbb`
2nd element: `ccc`

This is my try:

```
String x = "{aaa}{b}c";
return Arrays.stream(x.split("\\}"))
.map(ss -> {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ss);
matcher.find();
return matcher.group();
})
.toArray(String[]::new);
```

(assume only Java <= 8 allowed)

Comment: So it'll always be this pattern: "{aa}{bbbb}cc" ?

Comment: The pattern for *n* elements is not clear for me. Will the last element always be present without {}? So for n = 4, "{aaa}{bbbb}{ccc}dd"?

Comment: Too broad. What forms can the string assume?

Comment: what is actually the issue you're having? Do you insist on regex?

Comment: No, the String can be also: `{aaa}bbb` or `{aaa}{bbb}{ccc}ddd` or `{aaa}{bbb}{ccc}{ddd}eee` and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple replace should be enough if your strings are well formed like your examples:

```
String[] myStrings = {"{aaa}bbb", "{aaa}{bbb}{ccc}ddd", "{aaa}{bbb}{ccc}{ddd}eee"};
for(String str : myStrings){
    String[] splited = str.replace("}{", "}").replace("{", "").split("}");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splited));
}
```

prints:

```
[aaa, bbb]
[aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd]
[aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee]
```

Answer (score 1):

This way is a bit simpler than using regex (and may be a bit faster too):

```
String[] strings = new String[100];
int index = 0;
int last = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++){
    if(s.charAt(i) == "}"){
        strings[index++] = s.substring(last + 1, i - 1);
        last = i + 1;
    }
}
strings[index++] = s.substring(last, s.length());
```

If you want to use regex, the pattern needs to identify sequences of one or more letters, you can try the pattern `(?:{([a-z]+)})*([a-z]+)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static List<String> parse ()
  {
    String x = "{aaa}{b}c";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile ("[^{\\}]+(?=})");
    List < String > allMatches = new ArrayList < String > ();
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher (x);
    while (m.find ())
      {
            allMatches.add (m.group ());
      }
      String lastPart = x.substring(x.lastIndexOf("}")+1);
      allMatches.add(lastPart);
      System.out.println (allMatches);

    return allMatches
  }
```

Make sure you do a check for lastIndexOf >-1, if your string may or may not contain last part without braces.